# When calling the jquery function php is returning other columns

Tags: php, jquery

This is my jquery:

```
 <script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $container = $("#info_e1");

        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('stare-e1.php');
        }, 5000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Inside a table i have

```
<tr id='info_e1'>
<?php include 'stare-e1.php'?>
</tr>
```

And my php looks something like this:

```
<?php
......
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
     echo "<td><strong>Producator</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['producator']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Microcontroler:Port</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['uc'].":".$row['port']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Durata de aprovizionare</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['durata_aprovizionare']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Durata de viata</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['durata_viata']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Durata totala</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['durata_totala']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Ultima aprovizionare</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['data_aprov']." , ".$row['ora_aprov']."</td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><td><strong>Starea</strong></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['starea']."</td>";
}?>
```

When the page loads, the result of stare-e1.php is displayed perfectly. After  5 seconds, the jquery reloads '#info-e1' but instead of having the first row

```
<td><strong>Producator </strong></td>
<td></strong> fetched column of 'producator' </strong></td>
```

it changes to

```
 <td><strong>Starea</strong></td>
 <td></strong> fetched column of 'starea' </strong></td> ....
```

Am i missing something? I just cant figure it out why is it doing this? On reloading column starea appears  twice in my table, at the beginning instead of 'producator' and at the end where it should be. And if i change the value from mysql of 'starea' the updated value will be displayed on first row where 'producator' should be and on the last row where the duplicate is, it remains the old value.... Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to put some order in `fetchAll()` because it will fetch randomly and each time different value may get.